# Detect swipe right/ left in Fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, gesture, detection

i have a `viewpager` application working with three `fragments`´(*left, mid, right*). 
When i swipe from the ***mid*** `fragment` to the ***left*** `fragment` i want an animation to start in the ***left*** `fragment`.

Is there any way i can detect this *gesture* and implement functionality to it *easily*? If you need my code tell me, but i think this expanation should suit any needs of understanding what im trying to do.

Thanks!

Comment: Use a viewpager, it detects it for you

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html) which has the methods:

```
public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels)
public void onPageSelected(int position)
```

and decide what you need.

Alternatively, have a look at [`ViewPager.PageTransformer`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.PageTransformer.html)